# If a person undergoes an emergency baptism, then recovers, do they need a "non-emergency" baptism?

Tags: catholicism, baptism

If a person receives an emergency baptism, but then recovers from that danger, is that considered valid for the rest of their life? Or would they be expected to undergo a "non-emergency" baptism in the future?

In other words, is emergency baptism temporary or is it permanent?

Comment: Does this hypothetical person _want_ to be Baptized or did the guardian of that person just Baptize the person to get his sister of his case?  (asking for a non-hypothetical sad scenarios playing out in my life currently)

Comment: @PeterTurner I didn’t have any thoughts in mind for the person who underwent emergency baptism (if they were a baby, they wouldn’t have any), and imagined that the baptism was deliberately performed by the baptizer. It might be good to ask a separate question, or ask a non-hypothetical priest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A baptism is a baptism. There is no such thing as a "temporary baptism".

The key part of the Canons is as follows:

> An infant in danger of death is to be baptized without delay. (Canon 867 §2)

There is no provision for any kind of "rebaptism" or anything similar: indeed "only [a person not yet baptized] is capable of baptism" (Canon 864).

There are other rules about baptisms in case of necessity (imminent danger of death being the most common necessity). For instance, any person with the correct intent may baptize in necessity, not only a priest. None of these rules, however, suggest the emergency baptism is anything other than full, complete and efficacious.

Comment: But if there are any doubts about the validity of the baptism, one can also be baptized conditionally ("If you are not baptized, I baptize you ...").

Comment: I heard a story that Gran-ma baptized a child in the name of Jesus, Mary, and Joseph. The baby later became a priest and shared the story. Obviously, he needed to have all his sacraments redone.